# Summernote using Django forms displaying with HTML tags

Tags: django-forms, summernote

Hi So I have just set up summernote for the first time, however when I save all the HTML tags are displayed in another page where I am displaying the text. I want it to display the correct way without the HTML, thanks for any help :)

FORMS.PY

```
from django_summernote.widgets import SummernoteWidget, SummernoteInplaceWidget
from django import forms
from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title','content']
        widgets = {
            'content': SummernoteWidget(),
        }
```

VIEWS.PY

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
```

Form HTML

```
  <div class ='content-section'>
    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <fieldset class ="form-group">
          <legend class ="border-bottom mb-4">Post 1</legend>
          {{form|safe}}
      </fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class = "btn" type="submit">Post</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

display Post HTML

```
{% extends 'guide/base.html' %}
  {%block content%}
  {% if post.author == user %}
  <a href="{%url 'guide-update' post.id %}">Edit</a>
  <a href="{%url 'guide-delete' post.id %}">Delete</a>
  {% endif %}
          <div class = 'content'>
              <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
                <p></p>
                <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
          </div>
  {% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't include the safe in the html so

```
{{post.content|safe}}
```

did not include because I thought you only include the `safe` in the form